# C# - How can I have an type that references any object which implements a set of Interfaces?

Tags: c#, java, syntax, interface

How can I have a type reference that refers to any object that implements a set of interfaces?

For example, I can have a generic type like this:

**Java:**

```
public class Foo<T extends A & B> { }
```

**C#**

```
public class Foo<T> where T : A, B { }
```

That's how to have a class-wide generic type. However, I'd like to simply have a data member which references any object that extends a given set of interfaces.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    protected <? extends A, B> object;

    public void setObject(<? extends A, B> object)
    {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

If it's possible to have this sort of type syntax, how could I do it in both Java and C#?

---

I realize I can just create another interface that extends all desired interfaces. However, I don't see this as optimal, as it needlessly adds another type whose sole purpose is to get around syntax. Granted this is a very minor issue, but in terms of elegance it's a bit galling.

Comment: Struggling at the moment. In waht way does Foo.setObject add further behavior to A & B?

Comment: I gave an abstracted example. Here's a more concrete example:

I'm into game programming, my main game loop has two primary functions: an update and a render. In that, I delegate the calls to a "gameworld" object, which has its own render and update methods.

Only, I don't want to force my gameworld to only be instances of a particular class. I'd much rather split up the required functionality into a set of interfaces (in this case, Updateable and Renderable) and be able to use any object with implements all of them. It's a minor issue, but I think it's important in terms of elegance.

Comment: Why not just declare the private variable as type `A`, or type `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you can use a tuple to store the value in a kind of [*superposition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition):

```
public class Foo {
  private Tuple<IA, IB> junction;
  public void SetValue<T>(T value) where T : IA, IB {
    junction = Tuple.Create<IA, IB>(value, value);
  }
}
```

You can also have a specialized class to enforce the constraint that both values reference the same object:

```
public class Junction {
  public IA A { get; private set; }
  public IB B { get; private set; }
  private Junction() { }
  public static Junction Create<T>(T value) where T: IA, IB {
    return new Junction {
      A = value,
      B = value
    };
  }
}

public class Foo {
  private Junction junction;
  public void SetValue<T>(T value) where T : IA, IB {
    junction = Junction.Create(value);
  }
}
```

In Java, a wildcard would simplify things *a little*:

```
class Junction<E extends A & B> {
  private final E value;
  public Junction(E value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public E getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}

class Foo {
  private Junction<?> junction;
  public <E extends A & B> void setValue(E value) {
    junction = new Junction<E>(value);
  }
}
```

Or you can have *aliases* to the same value (C#, but also applicable to Java):

```
public class Foo {
  private IA a;
  private IB b;
  public void SetValue<T>(T value) where T : IA, IB {
    a = value;
    b = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I was asking for. I don't know if it's the best overall solution, since it requires some extra baggage, but it's effectively what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 4):

My Java has become a bit rusty through 2years of inactivity.

Here's my C# approach: (see https://ideone.com/N20xU for full working sample)

```
public class Foo
{
    private IInterface1 _object; // just pick one

    public void setObject<T>(T obj)
        where T : IInterface1, IComparable<T>, IEtcetera
    {
        // you now *know* that object supports all the interfaces
        // you don't need the compiler to remind you
        _object = obj; 
    }

    public void ExerciseObject()
    { 
        // completely safe due to the constraints on setObject<T>
        IEtcetera itf = (IEtcetera) _object;

        // ....
    }
```

Comment: While not optimal, I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? I tried several versions of it without any success...

Comment: @kol: of course. My answer is a snippet (in case the missing end bracket didn't give it away!). Here is a complete sample: https://ideone.com/N20xU (that site is slow today). HTH @majocha: I can see your point. I made `_object` private. Tread the balance between trusting the compiler and trusting your test coverage. Both options can work well.

Comment: It's a good attempt, but it's messy. (I especially don't like having to cast the object whenever I want to utilize the other interface.) I think I'd prefer to simply create a new interface if this is my only other option. +1 for the attempt, though.

Comment: @CodeBunny: if you don't like casting it, you can have accessors that return the appropriate interface. Otherwise, just bite the bullet and define that custom interface already :)

Comment: :) I'm fairly sure that's what I'll end up doing. Still, discussing design style is worthwhile.

Comment: The only other way I could think about getting around this (other than two private getters which cast it), would be to use `dynamic` as the private property.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, You cannot create a variable with constraints on it, you can only create a variable of a given type.  The type has the constraints.  This means you have to define a type that has the constraints you desire, then create the variable with that type.

This seems logical to me, and I don't see why you find it "galling" to have to define a type for what you need.

Comment: It's not galling because it's difficult; it's galling because it seems unnecessary to me. Needing to create a separate type to simply allow a type to use multiple, "lower-level" interfaces seems like a bad move. Interfaces by design lend themselves to a very flexible design, my question is in line with what I see as the logical extension of that.

Comment: Also, I feel that one should only create new types if one is actually adding functionality in them. Creating a new type for the sole purpose of blending interfaces seems backward.

Comment: @CodeBunny - It's no different than a delegate, in which you create a function signature type to use as an interface to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with simply stating the constraints as a private interface:

```
class Foo
{
    interface R : I1, I2 { }
    R _object;

    void setObject(R r) { _object = r; }
}
```

Comment: The main issue with adding an interface is that you need to modify every type that you want to accept to implement this interface. That can be ugly, or impossible depending on where these types are defined. And of course the interface needs to be at least as accessible as the `SetObject` method. [Talking about C# here, no idea about java]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I could come up with (but still not an optimal solution)

```
public class Foo
{
    private TypeWrapper<IInterface1,IInterface2> _object;
    public void setObject<T>(T obj)
        where T : IInterface1, IInterface2
    {
        _object = new TypeWrapper<IInterface1, IInterface2>();
        _object.SetObject(obj);

        var val = _object.Get(h => h.c);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        _object.Do(h => h.c = 25);
        val = _object.Get(h => h.c);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        _object.Do(h => h.someF());
    }
}

public class TypeWrapper<TType, TTypeTwo>
{
    private Object m_Obj;
    public void SetObject<T>(T obj) where T : TType, TTypeTwo
    {
        m_Obj = obj;
    }

    public T Get<T>(Func<TType, T> action)
    {
        return (T)action((TType)m_Obj);
    }
    public T Get<T>(Func<TTypeTwo, T> action)
    {
        return (T)action((TTypeTwo)m_Obj);
    }

    public void Do(Action<TTypeTwo> action)
    {
        action((TTypeTwo)m_Obj);
    }

    public void Do(Action<TType> action)
    {
        action((TType)m_Obj);
    }
}

public class myClass : IInterface1, IInterface2 {
    public int t {get;set;}
    public int c {get;set;}
    public void someF() { Console.WriteLine("Fired"); }
    }
public interface IInterface1 {
    int t { get;set;} 
    void someF();
}
public interface IInterface2 { 
    int c { get;set; }
}
```

You're going to have to work on the object through the Get and Do methods, but it'll work with intellisense and throw compile time errors if the interfaces change.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only ways to pass m_Obj to a generic method that expects a type constrained to both IInterface1 and IInterface2 are to either include the code which calls a generic method directly (not a delegate) within Foo, or else have Foo's constructor accept delegates for all such methods upon to which m_Obj should be passed, and store such delegates within Foo.  Neither approach seems attractive.