# Inherently-Implemented Interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have often wanted to create a list of objects where each object must implement a number of interfaces.  For example, I'd like to do something similar to the following:

```
List<T> where T : IConvertible, IComparable _myList;
```

Another option I considered was to create a third interface that implements these two so that any object that implements these two interfaces inherently implements mine.

```
public interface IConvertibleAndComparable
    : IConvertible, IComparable { }

List<IConvertibleAndComparable> _myList;
```

With this I would be able to add any object that implements both `IConvertible` and `IComparable`, including `double` and `int`, as well as my own objects.  Explicitly implementing `IConvertibleAndComparable` is not required since it does not add any new functionality beyond the interfaces in inherits.

I understand that the first snippet is illegal and the second, while legal, does not do what I want.  Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?  If not, would either of these be a candidate for a future C# feature?

(Note: This would be legitimate application for empty interfaces.)

**Edit**

In a more general sense, I'd like to perform one of the following:

```
private MyGenericClass<T> where T : IA, IB, ... _myClass;
```

where I can declare all of the restrictions on `T` that I need, *or*

```
public interface IMyCombinedInterface : IA, IB, ... {}
private MyGenericClass<IMyCombinedInterface> _myClass;
```

where any type that implements `IA`, `IB`, and `...` inherently (or implicitly) implements `IMyCombinedInterface` (only when `IMyCombinedInterface` doesn't explicitly declare new functionality).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand that, but why did you remove my "Thanks."?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really the place to propose new C# features.  You can ask if there is some way to do what you want, but if the answer is no, then we can't comment on what might or might not be added to C# in the future (until the feature set for the next version is publicly released)

Comment: @gregsdennis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I don't think this is possible but that would be a nice feature indeed. Another scenario where this would be helpful: MVVM with its ObservableCollections. Currently one has to use the concrete `ObservableCollection` class when all you really want is an `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `IList<T>`.

Comment: He is asking if it is possible, the C# feature comment is secondary to his question, not the question itself.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's exactly my use!  You get a prize.  (Prize to be awarded via textual gratitude.)

Comment: @gregsdennis: I solved this for me by switching to Caliburn.Micros `IObservableCollection` and the implementation `BindableCollection`.

Comment: Why was the previous answer removed?

Comment: @TimGoodman Not sure; owner self deleted.  I'm debating whether or not I should post another answer with the same code snippet or not.

Comment: @TimGoodman: The author removed it himself because it didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It doesn't do *exactly* what the OP wants, but chances are it's as close as you'll ever get in C#, so it's still worth posting.

Comment: @Servy: Well, not really. It wouldn't allow you to create an instance of a list to add float, double and a Person entity all into the same list, although all of those classes both implement `IConvertible` and `IComparable`. And that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @gregsdennis: I didn't want to add the following to my comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, as a workaround, do a kind of superposition wrapper, and store it in the list. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116245/31158) for the idea.

To your example you could do:

```
public class Junction
{
    public IConvertible Convertible { get; private set; }
    public IComparable Comparable { get; private set; }
    private Junction() { }
    public static Junction Create<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible, IComparable
    {
        return new Junction
        {
            Convertible = value,
            Comparable = value
        };
    }
}
```

And then add `Junction`s to your list:

```
var l = new List<Junction>();
l.Add(Junction.Create(1));
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I agree with the OP on that question in that there is definitely "extra baggage".

Comment: @gregsdennis: That's why it's a workaround. Now it's your prerogative to make a _balanced_ choice between this or some other solution, taking all pros and cons into account...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since it seems the most practical way of achieving the end goal _given the current limitations_.  Taking this further, however, you'd have to create a new Junction-like type every time you wanted to combine two interfaces, so it can get quite messy.

Comment: @gregsdennis: You could create a generic `Junction`.

Answer (score 0):

While working on another project, I had an idea for another workaround.  While it may not quite work for the example I posted, it could work for the original intent of the question, which was to create a combination interface for `IEnumerable<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` (as @DanielHilgarth pointed out).  The workaround is as follows:

Create an empty interface which implements the combination of interfaces you need.

```
public interface INotifyingEnumerable<T> :
    IEnumerable<T>,
    INotifyCollectionChanged
{
}
```

Create a new class which inherits from a class implementing both of these and implements the new interface.

```
public class MyObservableCollection<T> :
    ObservableCollection<T>,
    INotifyingEnumerable<T>
{
}
```

Now you can use the interface `INotifyingEnumerable<T>` as the property type, which using your implementation.

The reason this doesn't quite cover the original requirements, however, is that it doesn't allow `ObservableCollection<T>` to be directly assigned.  The feature requested in the original post would allow this.